# Why is the sum() of zero numbers not zero?

Tags: aggregate

For the following query

```
SELECT sum(c) 
FROM (SELECT 1 c WHERE false) t;
```

I thought it takes the sum of zero numbers, and therefore should return `0`. (Similarly, I expect, e.g. an array aggregate function to return an empty array on zero elements).

Yet, it is returning a `NULL` (using PostgreSQL 11).

```
=> SELECT sum(c) FROM (SELECT 1 c WHERE false) t; 
 sum 
-----

(1 row)
```

This doesn't make sense to me logically.

Why is the sum of zero numbers (for any numeric type) not zero? Is this NULL returning behavior standard?

Or maybe I am missing something. Any reason one has to make the sum `NULL` in some corner cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a requirement from the SQL standard. I'm most familiar with the [1992 standard](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). Quoting from it, with emphasis mine:

> General Rules
>
> 1) Case:
>
> a) If COUNT(*) is specified, then the result is the cardinality
>        of T.
>
> 6.5
>
> b) Otherwise, let TX be the single-column table that is the
>        result of applying the  to each row of T
>        and **eliminating null values**. If one or more null values are
>        eliminated, then a completion condition is raised: warning-
>        null value eliminated in set function.
>
> 2) If DISTINCT is specified, then let TXA be the result of elimi-
>   nating redundant duplicate values from TX. Otherwise, let TXA be
>   TX.
>
> Case:
>
> a) If the  COUNT is specified, then the
>        result is the cardinality of TXA.
>
> b) If AVG, MAX, MIN, or SUM is specified, then
>
> Case:
>
> **i) If TXA is empty, then the result is the null value.**

In short, NULLs are always excluded from the result of SUM, MAX, MIN, and AVG. I can't tell you exactly why this is, other than I think it's useful to be able to distinguish between a sum of a single value of 0 and a sum of an empty set.